# SQL Query to restrict return dates to current month

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, filter, getdate

I am trying to restrict my returned data to only those points that have start and end dates in the current month - active projects. It is behaving problematically because today is the last day of the month. I believe that tomorrow will be a problem as well (no June data included in the sample).

Here is my data set (Table 1):

```
Project                      User                 Effort  Start_Date End_Date
-------                      -------              ------  --------   --------
Traffic Control              DOMAIN\john.smith    0.1     5/1/2013   5/31/2013
Turboencabulator Analysis    DOMAIN\mark.webber   0       5/1/2013   5/31/2013
Widget Calibration           DOMAIN\mark.webber   0       5/1/2013   5/31/2013
Gizmo Creation               DOMAIN\steve.green   0.1     5/1/2013   5/31/2013
Advanced Toolmaking          DOMAIN\steve.green   0.6     5/1/2013   5/31/2013
Diesel Engine Diagnostics    DOMAIN\steve.green   0.05    5/1/2013   5/31/2013
Cold Fusion Reactor Creation DOMAIN\steve.green   0.3     5/1/2013   5/31/2013
```

When using the following query today I get no returned results:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1
WHERE Start_Date <= (getdate()) AND End_Date >= (getdate())
ORDER BY User, Start_Date
```

Yesterday it was returning just fine. I have data for June as well (not displayed in my sample) but I need to modify my statement such that it will reliably return data for the current month throughout the entirety of the month.

**Answer - Correct WHERE statement (from comments in answer below):**

```
WHERE (Month(Start_Date) <= Month((getdate())) AND Month(End_Date) >= Month((getdate()))) AND (YEAR(Start_Date) <= YEAR((getdate())) AND YEAR(End_Date) >= YEAR((getdate())))
```

Comment: Are start and end dates always the first and last date in the month?  Do "active" projects include those that started earlier or run later?  Would you like the results limited to the current year?

Comment: Limiting to the current year would be necessary... Perhaps I was too hasty lol. And I have the data input set up such that the start and and dates only ever fall in the beginning / end of the month.

Comment: Check underneath the answer for the final piece of the "WHERE" statement that met my needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use TSQL `Month` function:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1
WHERE Month(Start_Date) = Month(getdate()) AND Month(End_Date) = Month(getdate())
ORDER BY User, Start_Date
```

Comment: So you don't care about the year?  Any May will do?

Comment: Hmmm that is a valid point... I only put sample data up for May.

Comment: @Shrout1 in that case you can add check for `YEAR()` function as well

Comment: Just like to add that this was my final WHERE statement: `WHERE (Month(Start_Date) <= Month((getdate())) AND Month(End_Date) >= Month((getdate()))) AND (YEAR(Start_Date) <= YEAR((getdate())) AND YEAR(End_Date) >= YEAR((getdate())))`

Comment: Since you're looking for current month and year only I think you can replace <= and >= with =

Answer (score 11):

Just consolidate your `WHERE` statement into something like:

```
DATEDIFF(m, DATEFIELD, GETDATE()) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query can take advantage of indexes since it does not perform calculations on every row.  In addition, it returns as "active" any project that is active at any time during the month, e.g. a project that starts in the last week of the month and ends several months hence.  And it's easy to test and modify since it separates the date arithmetic from the query.

```
declare @Today as Date = GetDate()
declare @StartOfMonth as Date = DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( @Today ), @Today )
declare @EndOfMonth as Date = DateAdd( day, -1, DateAdd( month, 1, @StartOfMonth ) )

select @Today as [Today], @StartOfMonth as [StartOfMonth], @EndOfMonth as [EndOfMonth]

select *
  from Table1
  where Start_Date <= @EndOfMonth and End_Date >= @StartOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `convert(date, GetDate())GetDate()`.

Dates are represented as ticks, meaning smaller than seconds. if you compare GetDate() (which is 2013-05-31 11:09:45:1024 for exmaple, unsure about millisecond precision in mssql), it will always be greater than 2013-05-31, because of the hours/minutes/seconds. Your 2 choices are to  compare `YOURDATE >= Start_Date AND End_Date + 1 > YOURDATE`, or `YOURDATE >= Start_Date AND End_Date >= convert(date, YOURDATE)`

First options asks for it to be stricly less than the morrow of the end date (so basically the very end of that day), second one asks for it to be within the same day as the end date, ignoring ticks. Both yields the exact same result, one of them is probably more performant, however I can't help on that side of things.

EDIT : or you can use the other two's answer, except that it will only work if you always use monthly periods. and in that case it would be simpler to redesign your database to only have a 1-12 field representing the month.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, I use something similar to update data within x number of days, perhaps something like: 
`start_date <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);`
Just change 10 to whatever number of days you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for MySQL

`select date(date_joined),count(*) from users where MONTH(date_joined)=MONTH(now()) and YEAR(date_joined)=YEAR(now()) group by date(date_joined);`

Comment: Make use of proper text formatting. Use ` ` whenever writing code.